# Как в var загрузить файл?

Tags: jquery, javascript

Доброе время суток. :)

Как можно сделать так, чтобы var загружала файл? Например, вместо `var text = 'test'` было `var text = контент_с_url`.

Comment: Изучить javascript и/или jquery, не?

Comment: Уже были подобные http://hashcode.ru/questions/93819/javascript-как-в-переменную-загрузить-данные-из-файла ,  http://hashcode.ru/questions/320008/javascript-содержимое-txt-файла-передать-переменной-например-test-в-js

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**С [Jquery](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.get/) загрузка интернет-данных:**

```
//Load data from the server using a HTTP GET request.
$.get( "ajax/test.html", function( data ) {
  $( ".result" ).html( data );
  alert( "Load was performed." );
});
```

Относительно еще [load](http://api.jquery.com/load/) почитайте.

**[Чтение локальных файлов](http://www.htmlgoodies.com/beyond/javascript/read-text-files-using-the-javascript-filereader.html#fbid=SZ6Bo76-ddy):**

```
<input type="file" id="fileinput" />
<script type="text/javascript">
  function readSingleFile(evt) {
    //Retrieve the first (and only!) File from the FileList object
    var f = evt.target.files[0];

    if (f) {
      var r = new FileReader();
      r.onload = function(e) { 
          var contents = e.target.result;
        alert( "Got the file.n" 
              +"name: " + f.name + "n"
              +"type: " + f.type + "n"
              +"size: " + f.size + " bytesn"
              + "starts with: " + contents.substr(1, contents.indexOf("n"))
        );  
      }
      r.readAsText(f);
    } else { 
      alert("Failed to load file");
    }
  }

  document.getElementById('fileinput').addEventListener('change', readSingleFile, false);
</script>
```

Посмотри [здесь еще](http://www.html5rocks.com/ru/tutorials/file/dndfiles/), описывается взаимодействие с локальными файлами. Также милости прошу в google с запросами: js read text file, js get file, jquery get file, jquery load file и иные запросы вроде приведенных.

Да, и [сюда](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Using_files_from_web_applications) еще загляните, уж очень мне нравится их справка.

Удачи в учении! :)